# removeFromSuperView fine on iPod but crashes on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview

While changing between different views in an iPhone application I'm developing, I add and remove subviews from a larger view. I have written code which works on the iPod 4, iPhone 3, iPad 1, iPad 2, as well as the simulators. However, I get a bad access error on the iPhone 4 with the removeFromSuperView call. I know that its probably because I over released something so the superview no longer exists, but how is it that it worked on all the other devices?

Comment: Likely on other devices there weren't enough memory demand for the released are to be reused for something else, so it was still valid

Answer (score 0):

//  Try to do like following -

```
if(subview.superview!=nil)
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------

//   If  you have more view's then check view like this  -

```
for(UIView * subview in self.view) {

  if(subview == view1) {
    if(subview.superview!=nil)
       [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
else if(subview == view2){
    if(subview.superview!=nil)
       [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
   .
   .
   .
 }
```